# XAML styled button with multiple TextBlocks

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I've styled a `Button` element which contains two `TextBlock`s. One with the actual text and the other with an icon (from Segoe UI Symbol).

This is the code for the style:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonSettingsStyle" TargetType="Button">
    <Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
          <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60">
            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              ...
            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <TextBlock 
              x:Name="Icon"
              Text="&#xE115;"
              Margin="10,0,5,0" 
              Width="40"
              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
              FontSize="32"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
              FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock 
              x:Name="Text" 
              Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              Style="{StaticResource TextBlockListBoldItem}"
              Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
          </StackPanel>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

**Problem:**

I also want the Icon-TextBlock to have a custom icon, therefore a custom `Text`-property and to be used maybe like that (I really don't know how this should work):

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonSettingsStyle}" Content="Settings" IconContent="&#xE115;" />
```

How can I achieve this?
The `Content`-Setter is already assigned to the Text-TextBlock ...

*Thanks for your help!*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I agree with @meilke comment, but the problem is that you need a dependencyproperty to set a TemplateBinding so see new class ButtonWithIcon below

You should inherit from Button and add a DependencyProperty named IconContent :

```
public class ButtonWithIcon : Button
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IconContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IconContent", typeof (string), typeof (ButtonWithIcon), new PropertyMetadata(default(Icon)));

    public string IconContent
    {
        get { return (string) GetValue(IconContentProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IconContentProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

And use it like this :

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonSettingsStyle" TargetType="local:ButtonWithIcon">
  <Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:ButtonWithIcon">
        <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            ...
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <TextBlock 
            x:Name="Icon"
            Text="{Binding IconContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
            Margin="10,0,5,0" 
            Width="40"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
            FontSize="32"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"></TextBlock>
          <TextBlock 
            x:Name="Text" 
            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Style="{StaticResource TextBlockListBoldItem}"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>

<local:ButtonWithIcon Style="{StaticResource ButtonSettingsStyle}" Content="Settings" IconContent="&#xE115;" />
```

Comment: Also, you do not need the constructor. In this simple case `Button` will do everything that is needed.

Comment: Thanks for the suggested edit to my answer: But you can both use `{TemplateBinding bla}` and `{Binding bla, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}`

Comment: I just test it and it works only with Text="{Binding IconContent, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" for me ! Maybe I miss something ?!

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment. Now I understand how to extend components :-) I've got the same problem with `{TemplateBinding ...}`, which raises an exception. Only `{Binding .., RelativeSource=...}` works!

Answer (score 1):

Sub-class `Button` with a custom property `IconContent` to achieve that.

Here is the new class:

```
public class MyButton : Button
{
  public static readonly DependencyProperty IconContentProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("IconContent", typeof (string), typeof (ButtonWithIcon),   new PropertyMetadata(default(Icon)));

  public string IconContent
  {
    get { return (string) GetValue(IconContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IconContentProperty, value); }
  }
}
```

Here is the adjusted style (note the new `TemplateBinding` for `IconContent`):

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonSettingsStyle" TargetType="local:MyButton">
  <Setter Property="Content" Value=""/>
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MyButton">
        <StackPanel Background="Transparent" Orientation="Horizontal" Height="60">
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            ...
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <TextBlock 
            x:Name="Icon"
            Text="{TemplateBinding IconContent}"
            Margin="10,0,5,0" 
            Width="40"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
            FontSize="32"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" 
            FontFamily="Segoe UI Symbol"></TextBlock>
          <TextBlock 
            x:Name="Text" 
            Text="{TemplateBinding Content}"
            VerticalAlignment="Center"
            Style="{StaticResource TextBlockListBoldItem}"
            Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" />
        </StackPanel>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is the usage:

```
<local:MyButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonSettingsStyle}" Content="Settings" IconContent="&#xE115;" />
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. See my comment in Florent's post to see why I accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to subclass Button to add your own property, you could use the [Tag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.tag.aspx) property or [an attached property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011.aspx).

Note that if you use an attached property, you would need to bind to `TemplatedParent` instead of using `TemplateBinding`:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent},
         Path=local:AttachedProperties.IconContent}
```

I don't know why you would want to restrict your buttons to only accept text. Normally buttons accept any content and use [ContentPresenter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentpresenter.aspx)s. Personally, I would type the IconContent property as `object` and define the template like this:

```
<ContentPresenter x:Name="Icon" Content="{TemplateBinding IconContent}" />
<ContentPresenter x:Name="Text" />
```

Then set it like this:

```
<Button>
    <Button.IconContent>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource IconTextBlockStyle}" Text="&#xE115;" />
    </Button.IconContent>
</Button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This also seems to be a good way to solve my problem. The other solutions work better for me, 'cause this are specific buttons which really only need text (not all buttons in my app), and I need to write less XAML for them. But now I know how to do more complex styled buttons. Thanks to you!